# how come my array is not being rendered on my react page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone help me out and tell me why it is not rendering my array object. The data is being fetched from my Mongoose database which gets printed on the console, but how come it is not rendering on the page.

Thanks!

```js
class produce extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      fruits: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhos:2000/api/fruits')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(produce => {
        this.setState({ produce });
        console.log(produce);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          this text above shows
          {this.state.fruit.map(d => (
            <li key={d.id}>{d.fruit}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, links can become broken in the future. To make a good question, try to produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and take a look at [these questions tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlysonMaia I appreicrae the help, thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please consider marking it as correct so other people with the same issue can find the solution more easily. 

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `setState` function with the parameter `{ produced }`, you are creating the following state.

```js
{
  loading: true,
  fruit: [],
  produced: { data: [/* fruits data */] }
}
```

To avoid that, you need to access the property `data` in the API response and then assign it to the `fruit` property in your state.

The solution is changing the `setState`call to this.

```js
this.setState({ fruit: produce.data })
```